# Sending an SMS Message with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

how do i send an sms message from my web application using asp.net with c#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant send messages directly through asp.net.

What you can do is send a web request or an email to an online SMS provider,
or to a local gateway (like a phone) and it can then pass the message onto
the GSM network.

Try Clickatell to get an idea of what I mean.
http://www.clickatell.com/brochure/coverage.php

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pay, most cell phone carriers have an email that you can send messages to that will then forward them to the proper recipient. E.G. (10 digit phone number)@txt.att.net.

Bu of course this means that you will have to know the carrier, and many of them will not send outside the U.S. so that might not be the most attractive option.

Answer (score 0):

You find a gateway (I use [Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/), but there are others) and integrate with them. It's generally quite trivial (but of course, you pay to send the messages). They often have SMTP, HTTP and other types of APIs.